# Image Exact Size and Position After Rotating or Zooming in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

After searching lot of things but couldnt get help so asking the question.
I have a ImageView i am rotating that image with gesture now suppose if i had rotate it to some angle and zoom it through pan gesture. Now i want the same image size and position in next view so how can i do that with absolute position and size.

Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: How did you rotate the image... ? And what you mean with "absolute position and size"?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen rotating image with user interaction and suppose if i rotate image to some angle then i need to show same image in another screen with exact angle

Comment: I mean how you did it programmatically (e.g. via ImageView's transform or something else?). Anyway you seem to know the angle, so how about rotating the image by the same angle in the other screen?

Comment: I am doing this by Gesture Recognizer

Comment: You mean the `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`, then you should have the angle...

Answer (score 0):

To get `UIImage` size after zooming you can multiply image size by `UIScrollView`'s `zoomScale` property.

For Image size

```
Image.width = Image.width + ScrollView.contentOffset.x
Image.height = Image.width + ScrollView.contentOffset.y
```

For Image location

```
Image.x = (Image.x * ScrollView.zoomScale) - ScrollView.contentOffset.x
Image.y = (Image.y * ScrollView.zoomScale) - ScrollView.contentOffset.y
```